# How to display grouped data from two-dimensional array in HTML table?

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array, foreach, html-table

The following two-dimensional array stores information (Author, ID, and Title) for a collection of books:

```
$books = array(array('author'=>"AuthorA", 'ID'=>1, 'title'=>"titleA"),
               array('author'=>"AuthorB", 'ID'=>1, 'title'=>"titleA"),
               array('author'=>"AuthorC", 'ID'=>2, 'title'=>"titleB"),
               array('author'=>"AuthorC", 'ID'=>3, 'title'=>"titleC"),
               array('author'=>"AuthorD", 'ID'=>3, 'title'=>"titleC"));
```

I currently use a foreach loop to present this information in an HTML table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Book ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($books as $book): ?>               
    <tr>
        <td><?php htmlout($book['author']); ?></td>
        <td><?php htmlout($book['ID']); ?></td>
        <td><?php htmlout($book['title']); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

This code generates the following table:

```
Author  | Book ID |  Title 
AuthorA      1       titleA
AuthorB      1       titleA
AuthorC      2       titleB
AuthorC      3       titleC
AuthorD      3       titleC
```

**Question:** I would like to display the data in the following way:

```
Authors            | Book ID |  Title 
AuthorA, Author B       1       titleA
AuthorC                 2       titleB
AuthorC, Author D       3       titleC
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This might help... http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Your array doesn't have alphanumeric keys like you mention, e.g. `author`, `ID`

Comment: How are you grouping the authors together for books which have more than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$map = array();
foreach ($books as $book) {
    extract($book);
    $map[$ID][$title][] = $author;
}

foreach ($map as $ID => $entry) {
    foreach ($entry as $title => $authors) {
        printf(
            "<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n"
          , join(',', $authors)
          , $ID
          , $title
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this code (I used echo instead of htmlout):

```
<?php
$books = array(array("AuthorA", 1, "titleA"),
               array("AuthorB", 1, "titleA"),
               array("AuthorC", 2, "titleB"),
               array("AuthorC", 3, "titleC"),
               array("AuthorD", 3, "titleC")); 


function transform($books) {
   $result = array();
   foreach($books as $key => $book) {
      $id = $book[1];
      if (!isset($result[$id])) {
         $result[$id] = array(
            'author' => array(),
            'ID' => $book[1],
            'title' => $book[2]
         );        
      }
      $result[$id]['author'] = array_merge( $result[$id]['author'], array($book[0]));
   }
   foreach($result as $key => $data) {
     $result[$key]['author'] = implode(', ', $result[$key]['author']);
   }
   return $result;
}

$books = transform($books);

?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Book ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($books as $book): ?>               
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo($book['author']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo($book['ID']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo($book['title']); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Book ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
<?php
$books = array(array("AuthorA", 1, "titleA"),
               array("AuthorB", 1, "titleA"),
               array("AuthorC", 2, "titleB"),
               array("AuthorC", 3, "titleC"),
               array("AuthorD", 3, "titleC")); 
$prev_key = 0;
$authorColumn = "";
$titleColumn = "";
$rows = "";
foreach ($books as $book){
    if($prev_key == 0){
        $authorColumn = $book['0'];
        $titleColumn = $book['2'];
        $prev_key = $book['1'];
    }elseif($prev_key == $book['1']){
        $authorColumn .= ",".$book['0'];
        $titleColumn .= ",".$book['2'];
    }else{
        $rows .= "<tr>
        <td>".$authorColumn."</td>
        <td>".$prev_key."</td>
        <td>".$titleColumn."</td>
    </tr>";
        $prev_key = $book['1'];
        $authorColumn = $book['0'];
        $titleColumn = $book['2'];
    }

}
$rows .= "<tr>
        <td>".$authorColumn."</td>
        <td>".$prev_key."</td>
        <td>".$titleColumn."</td>
    </tr>";
echo $rows;

?>
</table>
```

This code is not clean but it's working correctly.